# Compute Riemann sums for double integral over regions in Python (TypeError)

Tags: python

I want to compute the Riemann sums of the double integral
[double integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsaqX.png)

```
f = lambda y,x: x*y/(x**2 + y**2)  
partition = 50


x = np.linspace(0.00001, 1, 200) 
y = np.linspace(1-x, 1, 200) 


def Riemann(function, x_low, x_up, y_low, y_up, x_part, y_part):

    dx = (x_up - x_low)/x_part
    dy = (y_up - y_low)/y_part
    dA = dx*dy
    sum = 0
    x_or = dx/2
    y_or = dy/2
    for m in range (0,x_part-1):
        for n in range (0,y_part-1):
            y_or += n*dy
            x_or += m*dx
            sum += function(y_or,x_or)*dA

    return sum
  
print(Riemann(f,0,1,lambda x:1-x,1,partition,partition))
```

But it returns this error:

```
TypeError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-fdd53b3a35ef> in <module>()
     17     return sum
     18 
---> 19 print(Riemann(f,0,1,lambda x:1-x,1,partition,partition))

<ipython-input-10-fdd53b3a35ef> in Riemann(function, x_low, x_up, y_low, y_up, x_part, y_part)
      4 
      5     dx = (x_up - x_low)/x_part
----> 6     dy = (y_up - y_low)/y_part
      7     dA = dx*dy
      8     sum = 0

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'
```

I really don't know how to solve this... But if i write

```
print(Riemann(function,0,1,1,0,x_part,y_part))
```

then it will return 0.34467033928271357, while the correct answer is 0.20387450858124856

Comment: Do you mean to be passing `lambda x:1-x` as your `y_low` argument?

Comment: What is `partition` in your original code? Without that information, the code is not reproducible. Also in the `Riemann` function, you should use `function` instead of `f` when calculating the sum at the end of the loop.

Comment: `sum` is a reserved word in Python, and it's actually a function for summing up list contents. You should rename this variable to something else (like `tsum` for temporary sum or `rsum` for Riemann sum, etc)

Comment: lambda x: 1-x is passed as my y_low argument for lower bound of y, while x runs from 0 to 1

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a function (instead of a float or integer) as parameter `y_low` to your function `def Riemann()`:

```
type(lambda x: 1-x)

function
```

Use the correct format and it should be solved

Comment: i did put a number instead but it returns incorrect answer, as it will integrate on a rectangle other than the region limit by x,y = 0 and x+y=1

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a function to a variable and then treating it as an integer.

```
print(Riemann(f,0,1,lambda x:1-x,1,partition,partition))
```

The code:

```
lambda x:1-x
```

will be treated as a function. If you want to pass in `1-x` then call the function with:

```
print(Riemann(f,0,1,1-x,1,partition,partition))
```

This will fix your current error but I am not entirely sure what it is you are trying to acheive.